# Populating ArrayList from variable TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to populate an arraylist by copying the string value of a TextView, process repeated whenever said TextView is changed(by pressing a button to change the text).
Now, i know the problem is tied to actually populating the arraylist, since i can display a predefined arraylist, and the textview also changes whenever the button does.

I've tried both

```
if(textView.getText().toString()!=null) {
  value = textView.getText().toString();
  datalist.add(value);
}
```

and

```
while(value==null){
        value=textView.getText().toString();
        datalist.add(datepicked);
        value=null;
        }
```

to no avail

Comment: add a text change listener to a TextView instead of checking text it TextVIew in cycle

Comment: Can you give Screenshot of UI & your requirement clearly to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code inside onClick method for the button whivh changes the TextView.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){ 
    if(textView.getText().toString()!=null) {
    value = textView.getText().toString();
    datalist.add(value);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot